# When Does Visual Studio 6 Catch Structured Exceptions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, visual-c++-6, seh

This is mostly curiosity, but I've been reading about the history of Visual Studio catching SEH exceptions in a C++ `try-catch` construct. I keep running across the assertion that older versions Visual Studio with the /GX flag enabled would "somtimes" catch structured Win32 exceptions in a C++ `catch` block.

**Under what circumstances will Visual Studio 6.0 enter the catch block in the following code when built with the /GX flag?**

```
char * p = NULL;

try
{
    *p = 'A';
}
catch(...)
{
    printf("In catch\n");
}
```

In my own simple tests with Visual Studio 6 + SP6 program execution halts with an unhanded exception and "In catch" is never printed. However, some articles (like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dcook/exceptional-wisdom) one) lead me to believe that it's possible to enter the `catch` block.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking about - what does "land it in the catch block" mean? Also, are you asking about the development environment or the runtime environment?

Comment: There were a couple of typos in that sentence. I've edited it to (hopefully) be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    __try
    {
        int *pInt = NULL;
        *pInt = 0;// throw some kind of exception
    }
    __except( EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER )
    {
        DWORD dw = GetExceptionCode();
        switch(dw)
        {
        case EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION:
            cout << "access violation\n";
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO:
            cout << "int divide by zero\n";
            break;
        case EXCEPTION_FLT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO:
            cout << "floating point divide by zero\n";
            break;
        // other cases
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thats Perhaps the only way I found Looking over the net.

Also as I can guess Even you know why it is not good to handle such exceptions, still for googlers coming here, do read :

http://members.cox.net/doug_web/eh.htm#Q1

Comment: Q2 in the link you provided answers my question exactly. Thanks!

Comment: I hoped that you had read it before asking, Seeing how easily I got it over google. Anyways good curiosity. Not All go & turn around looking for these. :)

Comment: Yeah, not sure how I missed that link. But, thanks for pointing it out.